# What percentage of arithmic progressions cross the middle

Tags: probability, arithmetic-progressions

Consider the first $n$ natural numbers and randomly pick $m$ numbers out of these. Define S as the set of these $m$ numbers, having density $d=m/n$. Consider all arithmic progressions of length 3 in S. What is the expectation of the proportion of these triples that crosses  $n/2$? That is, the progressions that start at < $n/2$ and have endpoint > $n/2$

Simulation seems to indicate that for sufficiently large $n$, the ratio is 0.5 when $d$ is close to 1 and 0.25 when $d$ is close to 0. Does that make sense?

Comment: What is "the ratio of these triples"? Suppose $n = 10$, so a progression $3, 6, 9$ satisfies the condition. What is the ratio of that triple? Or do you mean the expected **proportion** of all such triples that satisfy the condition?

Comment: It should be straightforward (by linearity of expectation) to consider the expectation of the number of middle-crossing 3-term APs and the expectation of the number of non-middle-crossing 3-term APs. That should give a pretty good indication what the typical behaviour of the ratio of those two quantities is, at least when both quantities are reasonably large (so $d$ close to $1$). When $d$ is close to $0$, perhaps most 3-term APs are disjoint and the expected ratio is the same as the probability that a randomly chosen 3-term AP in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ crosses the middle.

Comment: arithmic $\to$ arithmetic

Comment: I don't get it Greg. We definie each 3AP by the tuple of it's begin point and end point. For all  tuples (a, c) with a< c and a,c,$\in S$  we have that (a,c) is an 3-AP with probability P((a+c)/2 $\in  S) = d * 1/2 $ Why would the density matter

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $d=1$, then $S=\{1,2,3,...n\}$.

For an arithmetic progression $s_1,s_2,s_3$, assume that $s_1<s_2<s_3$. Now, we want to pick $s_1<n/2$ and $s_3>n/2$ in S. We can ignore $s_2$ here because there will definitely be a $s_2$ between $s_1$ and $s_3$. (of course we assume that $s_3-s_1$ is even. This will not matter since we will be comparing tuples containing arithmetic progression among themselves)

- $P(s_1 < n/2) = 0.5$
- $P(s_3 < n/2) = 0.5$

If both of these possibilities occur ($0.25$ possibility),  this is a situation we do not want.

- $P(s_1 > n/2) = 0.5$
- $P(s_3 > n/2) = 0.5$

Likewise, we do not want these two possibilities to occur together ($0.25$ possibility). Now, the sum of the possibilities we do not want is $0.5$. Then the situation we want is $0.5$.

So far everything is normal. You already stated that this ratio is 0.5 when d=1. If the set S shows a uniform distribution, $d$ will not affect the ratio you mentioned in any way. Because we can define S as a fuzzy set whose membership function is equal to a constant $d$:

$$S=\{1,2,3,...n\}, \  f(s_i)=d$$

Here $f$ is membership function of S. Thus, expected value of the number of elements of the set S will be $n.d=m$. And the solution above applies exactly the same here. From this perspective, it is clear that d will not change this ratio.

I think there must be something missing in your simulation. Because to be sure of my answer, I wrote a small code for this in Matlab and tried it. I saw that for d's close to 0, it was still 0.5.

Comment: Thanks, at least my intuition is better than my programming at least. I guess I counted something double or the opposite, Ill take a look. Thanks again